# git cherry pick from same branch

Tags: git

I've used git for about a couple of years in college, and if I'm being totally honest, I still have no clue what I'm doing.

I'm not sure if my title aptly describes the issue I'm having, but basically, I have made a bunch of commits to the master branch while developing a specific feature. Now that I'm at the end of developing this feature, my hindsight is showing me that this was a terrible idea, since I now need to commit and deploy only **the last couple of commits**.

Since those earlier commits are still being reviewed and awaiting approval, I can't just pull down everything onto my dev server. I've stumbled across `git cherry-pick` while attempting to figure this out, but apparently this is used to pull specific commits from a different branch... I think...

My question is, now that I'm in this bind, is there a way to only pull the last 2 or 3 commits from the master branch down without getting all of the changes that I don't want to include yet? I've read some other posts on SO, however I'm not sure that I understand the answers about cherry picking well enough to attempt these or if this would be appropriate in this case.

Comment: You _could_ pull down only the last X commits but the result will not be the one you'd expect, I assume. Couldn't you just create a new branch off of an earlier commit and cherry-pick the commits from master?

Comment: Yes, you can use cherry-pick to get the changes from just the 2 commit. You will not get the whole history. `git cherry-pick sha_of_commit`

Comment: What about reverting commits?

Comment: @Christoph what's the point of kipping _bad_ revisions from a private branch? It's better to just clean up history on a new branch, as recommended

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds like you have a branch with commits that you don't want and later commits that you do but you don't want to trash the branch:

```
master branch
A - B - C - D - E - F - G -H - I - J - K
             \                /     \ /
              Unwanted commits     Good commits
```

You need a new branch.

```
git switch -c new-branch
```

and you need to reset it to before the work you don't want.

```
git reset --hard <hash-of-commit-C>
```

Now you can cherry-pick the commits you want from `master`.

```
git cherry-pick <hash-of-commit-J> <hash-of-commit-K>
```

Or, to select a range of commits

```
git cherry-pick <hash-of-commit-J>..<hash-of-commit-K>
```

If you like the result, you can replace your branch with this

```
git branch -f master # set master where I am right now
git switch master
```

And you are done.

Comment: This is clean solution. However, what if I want a certain commit, say commit G, later. Will it be even possible.

Comment: @Jayz yes, you can simply `cherry-pick` that commit as well. If you replaced the branch and it has been some time then the commit may have been garbage collected. To preserve the old branch, make sure you keep a reference to it (a branch or tag).

Answer (score 3):

You could just do it like this:

```
git checkout new-branch origin/master # or use whatever branch/revision you think it's ok to start from
git cherry-pick old-branch~2..old-branch # cherry pick the last two revisions of old-branch
```

If you like the result, you can replace your branch with this

```
git branch -f old-branch # set old-branch where I am right now
git checkout old-branch
```

And you are done.

Comment: FYI I'm copying your last two commands to replace the old branch, so that the accepted answer is the most complete. It's already got a diagram, so it seems like the best way unless someone has the power to merge both answers. (Not me. :)